# What is the best way to iteratively instantiate a class from a dictionary of lists/arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I have dataset read from a textfile of many columns, each column of which corresponds to a dictionary key. As such, each dictionary key corresponds to a value that is an array. I would like to instantiate a class instance for all keys on a per index basis. **The sample snippet below works, though I am wondering if there are better ways to do this** (better in terms of speed, being pythonic, etc).

First I initialize some sample data.

```
import numpy as np

ts = np.array([0, 2, 6, 10])
ss = np.array([100, 90, 120, 130])
ns = np.array(['A', 'C', 'G', 'K'])

data = dict(time=ts, size=ss, name=ns)
print(data)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
{'name': array(['A', 'C', 'G', 'K'],
      dtype='<U1'), 'time': array([ 0,  2,  6, 10]), 'size': array([100,  90, 120, 130])}
```

Then I create a sample class and instantiate per index of an arbitrary array (since they are all of the same size).

```
class SampleProblem():

    def __init__(self, time, size, name):
        self.time = time
        self.size = size
        self.name = name

res = []
for idx in range(len(data['time'])):
    res.append(SampleProblem(data['time'][idx], data['size'][idx], data['name'][idx]))
# not written as a list comprehension for readability purposes

for idx in range(len(res)):
    print(res[idx].name)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
A
C
G
K
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is one Pythonic alternative:

```
res = [SampleProblem(t, s, n)  for t, s, n in \
       zip(data['time'], data['size'], data['name'])]
```

Possibly a better idea is to realign your dictionary with `zip` before a list comprehension:

```
data = dict(enumerate(zip(ts, ss, ns)))
# {0: (0, 100, 'A'), 1: (2, 90, 'C'), 2: (6, 120, 'G'), 3: (10, 130, 'K')}

res = [SampleProblem(*args) for args in  data.values()]
```

Comment: Assuming a dataset composed of ~70,000 data points per key and ~15 keys, is this feasible? I can't seem to find the source right now, but I read somewhere that zip isn't necessarily memory-efficient.

Comment: `zip` should definitely be memory efficient, it's lazy since it only gets one set of inputs at a time. It's not, however, the fastest, since you are still performing some kind of loop. For a custom class, I can't see a way of avoiding that loop.